# What are the non functional requirements for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am working on a proposal for SharePoint online, and I need to list and describe the non-functional requirements for SharePoint Online, such as performance, security, reliability, etc.

Can anyone help from where I can read more about these?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here are a few articles that might help you：**

- [SharePoint limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits)
- [SharePoint Non-Functional Requirements](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/sharepoint-non-functional-requirements/)
- [SharePoint Online limitations and boundaries](https://mstechtalk.com/sharepoint-online-limitations-and-boundaries/)
- [WHY YOUR BUSINESS NEEDS TO START USING SHAREPOINT ONLINE](https://www.advantageservices.net/blog/90/Why-Your-Business-Needs-to-Start-Using-Sharepoint-Online)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but  what i am asking about is a documentation listing these non-functional requirements for SharePoint online @ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement#Examples